# Distance from light to flower box

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

how I can measure distance of light to flower box? As I'm making a game where you can grow vegetables and I would like to make it so, that if lighting is more than 5 meters away, your vegetables wont grow. Also then when player picks up a light it would show distance to nearest flower box? They have their own tag of "flowerbox" and lights have their own "lights"

Thank you so much for your answers!

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html

Answer (score 0):

I could give you *A* solution, but it would make a lot more sense to craft a solution around your current work.

What you want to keep in mind is that if you're dealing with GameObjects in a 3D scene (something you didn't specify), you can find the distance between two objects by looking at their world positions (as opposed to their `localPosition`)

The distance between two GameObjects is simply:

```
var distance = (light.transform.position - flowerBox.transforn.position).magnitude;
```

That will give you a float value, which will be the distance in Unity units (defacto of 1 unit = 1 metre).

The magnitude docs are [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try this next time I open Unity3d :)

Comment: Why not simply use [`Vector3.Distance(light.transform.position, flowerBox.transform.position)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) which does exactly that ;)

Comment: There is a typo in your answer, "transforn" instead of "transform".

Answer (score 0):

The distance between the light source and your flower box depends on the type of light you're using and the specific needs of the plants in the box. Here are some general guidelines:

```
Natural Sunlight:
    If your flower box is outdoors and receives direct sunlight, there's no specific distance to consider. Just ensure that the plants receive the recommended amount of sunlight based on their specific requirements.

Artificial Grow Lights:
    For indoor flower boxes with artificial grow lights, the distance varies based on the type of light:
        Fluorescent Lights: Keep them 6 to 12 inches above the plants.
        LED Grow Lights: Usually, they can be kept 12 to 24 inches above the plants.
        High-Intensity Discharge (HID) Lights: These lights should be kept at a greater distance, typically 24 inches or more.
```